# Button error in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox, button

I have a button with an onclick event.  I use the same button on two separate pages, but with different text and a different onclick event.

The button has a radius border.  The radius border is invisible until I mouse over the button, and the radius will show if I click on the text.

```css
.new_button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 35%;
  height: 2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: roboto_lightregular;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" class="new_button" value="Word Wordwor Wor" onclick="ShowForm(20)" />
</form><br><br>
```

When I mouse over the button the cursor will change to pointer and the radius border will appear, but only if I mouse over anywhere from Word Wor but not if I mouse over the letters to the right of Wor (in the area dwor Wor.  In other words, the hyperlink works on the left side of the button but not on the right side.

This problem does not occur in Chrome at all.  I’ve had a lot of trouble with buttons and hyperlinks failing totally or partially in Firefox.

Has anyone else seen this problem in Firefox?  Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: There is no such property as `font-color`. What is the expected result? Can you please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]? There is no border apperaing upon hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works perfectly for me in Firefox 67.

```css
.new_button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 35%;
  height: 2vw;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-family: roboto_lightregular;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.new_button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border: thick double #32a1ce;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" class="new_button" value="Word Wordwor Wor" onclick="ShowForm(20)" />
</form><br><br>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `:hover` attribute in css, so your css would look like this

```
.new_button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 35%;
  height: 2vw;
  font-family: roboto_lightregular;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13pt;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.new_button:hover{
border: 0px 20px 0px 20px solid #000000;
transition: .3s;

}
```

and your html:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" class="new_button" value="Word Wordwor Wor"/>
</form><br>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hover code, but it does not change the strange behavior.  Also, in your suggested htmp you have removed the onclick event.  Where would that go?

Comment: @RTC222 The `onclick` would go in exactly the same place.

Comment: How does adding the `:hover` pseudo-class resolve the described browser discrepancy?

Comment: It doesn't change it.  The problem is Firefox only.

Comment: @RTC222 you might have to keep it, mess around with css' ```:active``` attribute and see if that can help, if not you might want to put it back in or before the tag insert the function in, as the error i see is that ShowForm isnt defined, luckily HTML has a tag for your JS, its the ``` <script> ``` tag, look into that also

Comment: The problem appears to have been a Firefox add-on.  I just don't know which add-on.  When I disabled five of them the problem has disappeared .